# API 23 Emulator Is Not Starting

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have API 23 Marshmallow.

Settings:
Nexus S 4.0" 480x800 hdpi
Marshmallow Android 6.0 x86
RAM 1536 MB

While running emulator getting this error:

[image]

I tried to install HAXM but it says my system not supporting Virtualization Technology. Mine is intell i3-4010U.
But while running emulator with API 22 its all fine.

Any idea about this.

Comment: add please configuration for 22 API. I think it's working because ARM

Comment: install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator(HAXM installer) from android-sdk/extra these are new with android 6.0

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar I've mentioned I tried but it say some error. system not supporting Virtualization Technology

Comment: @RaghavendraShivhare: you have windows PC 64 or 86? or mac os x? Linux?

Comment: @piotrek1543 man you are correct arm is the issue. Can you tell y ?

Comment: well, now I am not sure. As I saw on Intel page, your processor supports VT-x technology - so I see two possibilities - you have already running Microsoft Hyper-V hardware accelaration or you haven't enabled Virtualization technology in your laptop BIOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 0. Introduction

first of all - your processor supports hardware accelaeation (VT-x):
http://ark.intel.com/products/75107/Intel-Core-i3-4010U-Processor-3M-Cache-1_70-GHz

#### 1. `Hyper-V` is already running

I see you're using Windows, did you already install Hyper-V or Visual Studio (it might installed with it). If yes I suppose you to follow these tutorial (find `Using HAXM and Hyper-V` section)

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/accelerating_android_emulators/

Your system may running already another hardware accelaration called Hyper-V. Ypu need to disable or unistall it.

#### 2. `VT-x` is not enabled

Propably you don't have enabled virtualizarion technology and your previous emulator run on ARM base technology, which doesn't need to have a VT technology. It can run even on 32-bit old processors.

Go to your `BIOS` and find a point like `Virtualization Technology Enabled  - NO`. On different machines it may be different called so try to find on Web how to run BIOS for your laptop and where to find a VT technology.

Hope it help

Comment: Visual studio was installed earlier thanks I'll try.

Comment: As I said - find if Hyper-V was with it installed or check your BIOS configuration - you may not enabled this function

Comment: Thanks a lot Hyper-V was the problem. Cheers, Happy New Year.

Comment: Thanks. I'm glad that I could help

Answer (score 0):

**You have to install Intel HAXM Properly**

```
      First Of All Open Android SDK Manager.
      1) Go to Packages then checked both options Show Updates/New Packages As Well As Show Installed Packages. 
      2) Then Go to Extras Select Intel X86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM Installer)
      3) Install It From the web then restart PC then try.

     IF You Already Have HAXM Installed And also got this
     Go to Your Android SDK Directory. Then go to android-sdk then extras intel then double click or run intelhaxm-android.exe manually. It will definitely hepls you.
```

Answer (score 0):

go to BIOS >> advanced >> and set virtualization to enabled
then Install intelhaxm.exe in this path:

```
<your sdk path> -> extras -> intel -> intelhxm.exe
```

if you dont have this folder in your sdk manager you should download it by `SDKManager >> Intel x86 accelerator...`